# IDA Python - Find highlighted register

Tags: idapython

In IDA's Graph View, when we select some register (for example, `esp` in the image below), every location that the register occurs is highlighted.

Is it possible to read what the selected operand is? (I want to work with registers at the moment, but it would be nice to be able to know any selected value).

I am able to get the address of the instruction using `idaapi.get_screen_ea()`, but am unable to proceed further.

[image: esp highlight]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
idaapi.get_highlighted_identifier()
```

This function returns highlighted text. All the IDAPython reference can be found at [here, at Hex-Rays site](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/)

Answer (score 2):

In case the above doesn't work in newer versions try `ida_kernwin.get_highlight(ida_kernwin.get_current_viewer())`

Example:

```
Python>ida_kernwin.get_highlight(ida_kernwin.get_current_viewer())
('edx', 0x3)
```

The backwards compatibility layer shows how to interpret the returned tuple:

```
def get_highlighted_identifier():
    thing = get_highlight(get_current_viewer())
    if thing and thing[1]:
        return thing[0]
```